# repo merge between different Android Repository

Tags: android, git, repository

I am MW

I am trying to merge 2 repositories of Android.

Let's say `Repo A` is original source and `Repo B` is same as `Repo A` except for that `Repo B` has a few new projects and some updates.

In order to merge, I try command with: `$ repo forall -c git push Repo B to Repo A`:

```
"New Project" does not appear to be a git repository.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

My question is how to add new projects of Repo B to Repo A.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your questions correctly you have 2 different repository on a remote server. Like remotehost:~/repos/repoA and /repos/repoB.
So if A and B are the same besides some new directories, why do you even have to different repositories instead of 2 branches?
You could clone repoB to your local machine. Afterwards edit the .git/config and change the origin master from url = ssh://youruser@yourserver/path/to/repoB to the repository of repoA temporarly.
Then you could check the status and add, commit and push into your other repository.
Hope that was what your looking for but for nearly identical projects it's better to have only one repository and different branches. For the deployments your could use capistrano to deploy different branches to different servers.

Cheers